# I want to firstly create a database and then update it as per the values in mongodb

Tags: python, database, mongodb, upsert, robo3t

I want to update the value of Entry1 using upsert. I have a sensor that returns the value of Entry1. If sensor is blocked, the value is true. If sensor is not blocked then the value is False.

machineOne = None
oneIn = 1
while True:
    global machineOneId
    global userId
    try:
        if Entry1.get_value() and oneIn < 2:

```
        machineOne = Entry1.get_value()
        print('entered looopp ONeeeE', machineOne)

        machine1 = {
            'Entry1': Entry1.get_value(),
            'Exit1': Exit1.get_value(),
            'id': 'test'
        }
        result = Machine1.insert_one(machine1)
        myquery = {"Entry1": 'true'}
        newvalues = {"$set": {"id": result.inserted_id}}

        #result = Machine1.insert_one(machine1)
        Machine1.update_one(myquery, newvalues)
        userId = result.inserted_id
        oneIn += 1
        print('added', result.inserted_id, oneIn)

    elif machineOne:
        print('entered looopp', userId)

        myquery = {"id": userId}

        newvalues = {"$set": {"id": Entry1.get_value()}}
        upsert = True

        #result = Machine1.insert_one(machine1)
        Machine1.update_one(myquery, newvalues)

    if Exit1.get_value():

        print('added',)

finally:
    print('nothings happened', machineOne)
```

what is expected: i should be able to update the Entry1 from true to false in the same log, displayed in robo3t

Answer (score 0):

Good Afternoon @digs10 ,

I read your post and I think the error is how you locate the document that you want to update.

I remember that MongoDB document primary key is "_id" instead of "id". You could take a look here [MongoDB Documents](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/document/)

For what I see in the code (I don't know Python but it is readable), you are referring to the document "Entry1" using the field "id" instead of "_id.

Try modifing the line `myquery = {"id": userId}` for `myquery = {"_id": userId}`.

I hope this answer can help you.

Best Regards,

JB

P.S: I saw this question in my email and I took a quick read of it, If I misunderstood it, please let me know.